# Creating a Generic instance of type using static method in Java

Tags: java, generics, methods, instance

Hi I have **generic** java class

```
public abstract class Ref<Id> {
    private Id id;

    public Id getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public void setId(Id id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public static <Id> Id getValue(Ref<Id> reference) {
       return reference != null ? reference.getId() : null;
    }
}
```

**where**

**Id** is just *literal* like E,K,V

And I saw strange variable creation

```
public class FirstClass {

public ManuId create(SecondClass second) {
 (1)    ManuId manuId = Ref.getValue(second.getManu());
        assert manuId != null;

        return manuId ;
    }
}
}
```

and

```
public class SecondClass {
     private ManuRef manu;
     public ManuRef getManu() {
       return manu;
     }
}
```

and:

```
public class ManuRef extends Ref<ManuId> {
}
```

and:

```
public class ManuId{}
```

So the problem is in line marked with (1)

```
   (1)  ManuId manuId = Ref.getValue(anotherObject.getRef());
```

I am wondering why creation of instance is possible in way like that? Why we do not have to specify **ManuId** type like this (2):

```
(2) ManuId manuId = Ref.<ManuId>.getValue(second.getManu());
```

Why Java allows (1).

PS: This is edited version of the topic.

Comment: Create a complete snippet of code that demonstrates what is confusing.

Comment: Confusing is (1) why Java allows this kind of construction.

Comment: I fail to see how this code could compile to begin with. Please demonstrate that it does indeed compile by providing an example illustrating the issue.

Comment: Thanks for note @aiobee. For me is even hard to formalize my question.

Comment: The question is in a much better form now. Good cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `Id` in the method declaration shadows the `Id` type parameter on the class level, so the fact that `Ref` is a generic class has little to do with this. Your code is equivalent if you just change the method declaration to

```
public static <T> T getValue(Ref<T> reference) {
   return reference != null ? reference.getId() : null;
}
```

Second, since the method accepts a `Ref<T>` and you provide it with a `Ref<ManuId>` it understands that `T` must be bound to `ManuId`. This is called [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

So, in other words, you don't need to do `Ref.<ManuId>getValue(second.getManu());` (although it is perfectly valid) because

- ...the type variable does not belong to the class, but to the method, so you don't need to give a type parameter when referring to the `Ref` class, and
- ...the type argument is *inferred* by the compiler by looking at the argument you provide at the call.